# Получить доступ к primaryStage из другого класса?

Tags: java, javafx

Как это сделать? Хотелось бы при получении определенного события разворачивать свернутое окно. Есть класс `Main`, в котором:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("design.fxml"));
    try {
        rootLayout = (Pane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setPrimaryStage(Stage pStage) {
    Main.pStage = pStage;
}

public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return pStage;
}
```

В контроллере есть метод, который, как хотелось бы, разварачивал окно, которое свернуто или находится за другими окнами:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override 
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
            Main.getPrimaryStage().toFront();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        while(!flag)
        { .....}
});
```

Но при вызове этого метода по событию возникает ошибка:

> This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = Thread-14

Comment: `Platform.runLater( () -> {Main.getPrimaryStage().toFront();} );`

Comment: Andrey M - спасибо огромное, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант, дать контролеру `primaryStage`, чтобы не привязывать его к классу, инициализировавшему его.

В контроллере завести переменную `Stage primaryStage` и сеттер к нему.

В классе, который инициализирует сцену можно получить контроллер из fxml файла так:

```
Controller controller = rootLayout.getController();
```

и потом передать ему сцену через сеттер:

```
controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
```

---

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("design.fxml"));
    try {
        rootLayout = (Pane) loader.load();
        Controller controller = rootLayout.getController();
        controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setPrimaryStage(Stage pStage) {
    Main.pStage = pStage;
}

public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return pStage;
}
```